# Can I show some part of the next slide in carousel? Is it feasible? (react, web, react-material-ui-carousel)

Tags: css, reactjs, carousel

I am intending to show some part of the next slide with a lib, react-material-ui-carousel(https://github.com/Learus/react-material-ui-carousel).

As you may see, some part of the next slide is visible on the first slide. This is what the customer pursues.... Is it feasible by using react-material-ui-carousel or other libs of react? I've looked through all documents on Google but couldn't make it...

I would really appreciate if you give me some suggestions or tips.

[image: ref]

Comment: have you tried this ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel